# React Semantic UI - Step Component not displaying properly on Card

Tags: css, reactjs, semantic-ui-react

I am using semantic UI for React visual components.
There are issues with displaying the Step components contained within the Card Designed. Although, I have set the Card component to be fluid in the code shown below.

```
<Card fluid raised>
```

When viewed through a desktop, it overflows to the outside of the Card like shown below:[image]

However, it works just fine when viewed through a mobile. It stacks up vertically well within the Card component like shown below:
[image]

My Code is as Given Below.

```
// Confirmation.jsx
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Label, Header, Card, Form, Button, Container, Icon, Step } from 'semantic-ui-react';




class Confirmation extends Component{
    saveAndContinue = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        this.props.nextStep();
    }

    back  = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        this.props.prevStep();
    }

    render(){
        const {values: {  companyName, phoneno, email, subscription, shopregno, gstin, ownername, owneremail, ownerphone, customerservice, address, position  }} = this.props;

        return(


            <Container>
              <Header as='h2' icon textalign='center'>
                              <Icon name='users' circular />
                              <Header.Content>REGISTRATION</Header.Content>
                </Header>
            <Card.Group>
             <Card fluid raised>
               <Card.Content>
                  <Card.Header>
                  <Step.Group>
                    <Step completed>
                      <Icon name='user' />
                      <Step.Content>
                        <Step.Title>Customer Details</Step.Title>
                        <Step.Description>Enter the customer details</Step.Description>
                      </Step.Content>
                    </Step>

                      <Step completed>
                      <Icon name='map marker alternate' />
                      <Step.Content>
                        <Step.Title>Map Details</Step.Title>
                        <Step.Description>Enter Location information</Step.Description>
                      </Step.Content>
                    </Step>


                    <Step completed>
                      <Icon name='book' />
                      <Step.Content>
                        <Step.Title>Category Details</Step.Title>
                        <Step.Description>Enter Category information</Step.Description>
                      </Step.Content>
                    </Step>

                    <Step completed>
                      <Icon name='servicestack' />
                      <Step.Content>
                        <Step.Title>Service Details</Step.Title>
                        <Step.Description>Enter Service information</Step.Description>
                      </Step.Content>
                    </Step>

                    <Step completed>
                      <Icon name='address card' />
                      <Step.Content>
                        <Step.Title>Owner Details</Step.Title>
                       <Step.Description>Enter Owner information</Step.Description>

                      </Step.Content>
                    </Step>

                   <Step active>
                       <Icon name='info' />
                      <Step.Content>
                        <Step.Title>Confirm Registration</Step.Title>
                        <Step.Description>Finalize & Confirm</Step.Description>

                      </Step.Content>
                    </Step>

                  </Step.Group>

                  </Card.Header>
               </Card.Content>





             <Card.Content extra>

                <Button secondary onClick={this.back}>Back</Button>
                <Button primary onClick={this.saveAndContinue}>Save And Continue </Button>
             </Card.Content>



         </Card>
       </Card.Group>





    </Container>



        )
    }
}

export default Confirmation;
```

I tried a method suggested by Jake, which adds on a scrollbar to the Step.Group as shown Below:
[image]

Not really an ideal solution, since the scrollbar doesn't auto-move to the active step.

Any Help will be highly appreciated, to solve this bug.
From the documentation of semantic UI, I understand there is a  width preset for the Card Component. How does one modify this preset width by overriding it?

Comment: ["A fluid card takes up the width of its container"](https://semantic-ui.com/views/card.html#fluid-card). Try removing the fluid class or set `max-width` or `overflow: auto` on your element (Step.Group here I believe) and see if that solves your issue.

Comment: Tried that already and no dice, didn't work. This is in React-semantic-ui , so I tried setting - style={{ overFlow: "auto" }} and max-width too maxWidth. Did it on the card and Step.Group. Thanks for the response though.

Comment: Write it like this `<Step.Group style={{overflow: 'auto', maxWidth: 100% }}></Step.Group>` (overflow instead of overFlow) and see if that works.

Comment: Thanks Jake, it sorta worked, doesn't expand the card but brings in a scrollbar for the step group. Not an ideal solution, but at least it's workable. However, on moving down the steps. the scrollbar doesn't move automatically. Any suggestion for that.

Comment: Multiple solutions : 1. Only show icons and show the text only for the selected / active element. 2. Use ellipsis on your elements and set your overflow to hidden instead of auto. 3. Modify your design ;)